# Journals publishing long articles

Tags: journals

I wanted suggestions on high quality journals that frequently publish long articles (70-110 pages) on stochastic analysis and/or pde's.

Comment: Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society.

Comment: Another possibility is [Dissertationes Mathematicae](https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/dissertationes-mathematicae).